# Loop Portfolio Next/Previous Button in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, portfolio

I am new in php, so I like to get some help.

My clients want the next and previous button to be looped in the single page portfolio. Well this is the code I am using.

```
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
$next_post = get_next_post();
$prev_post_link = !empty($prev_post) ? get_permalink($prev_post->ID) : true;
$next_post_link = !empty($next_post) ? get_permalink($next_post->ID) : true;
if(!empty($prev_post) && empty($prev_post_thumb)) $prev_post_thumb = prev_next_post_format_icon($prev_post->ID);
if(!empty($next_post) && empty($next_post_thumb)) $next_post_thumb = prev_next_post_format_icon($next_post->ID);
?>
```

When I use True, for both the Previous & Next Links, Its appearing in the first and last portfolio, but the hyperlink is showing as http://1 and not the next portfolio. Thanks in Advance

This my html code:

```
<div class="dfd-controls mobile-hide">
<?php if(!empty($prev_post_link)) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($prev_post_link); ?>" class="page-inner-nav nav-prev">
        <div class="dfd-controler prev">
        <div style="margin-top:7px; color:#fff;">Previous</div>
            <!-- <div class="thumb prev"> 
                <?php echo $prev_post_thumb; ?>
            </div> -->
        </div>
        <!--<div class="pagination-title">Previous Project</div> -->
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(!empty($next_post_link)) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($next_post_link); ?>" class="page-inner-nav nav-next">
        <div class="dfd-controler next">
            <div style="margin-top:7px; color:#fff;">Next</div>
            <!-- <div class="thumb next">
                <?php echo $next_post_thumb; ?>
            </div>-->
        </div>
        <!--<div class="pagination-title">Next Project</div>-->
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the value from true to false. Setting a variable to true will give `empty` a false value [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Now 'next' will only show if there is a next post

your PHP should be:

```
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
$next_post = get_next_post();
$prev_post_link = !empty($prev_post) ? get_permalink($prev_post->ID) : false;
$next_post_link = !empty($next_post) ? get_permalink($next_post->ID) : false;
if(!empty($prev_post) && empty($prev_post_thumb)) $prev_post_thumb = prev_next_post_format_icon($prev_post->ID);
if(!empty($next_post) && empty($next_post_thumb)) $next_post_thumb = prev_next_post_format_icon($next_post->ID);
```

**UPDATE: To have the posts loop:**

```
if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', true) ) { 
    previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="dfd-controler prev"><div style="margin-top:7px; color:#fff;">Previous</div></div>');
} else { 
    $first = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><div class="dfd-controler prev"><div style="margin-top:7px; color:#fff;">Previous</div></div></a>';
    wp_reset_query();
}; 

if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ) { 
    next_post_link('%link', '<div class="dfd-controler next"><div style="margin-top:7px; color:#fff;">Next</div></div>');
} else { 
    $last = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=ASC'); $last->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><div class="dfd-controler next"><div style="margin-top:7px; color:#fff;">Next</div></div>';
    wp_reset_query();
};
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Well If I am in the first post, I should be able to go to the previous post i.e. is the last post likewise if i am in the last post , i should got the next post i.e is the first post. It should be like a loop. what should be done for that?

Answer (score 0):

**Loop Portfolio Next/Previous Button in Wordpress**

```
     <div class='next_post_link_align'>
<?php next_post_link('<span class="previous_post_link">&larr; %link </span> <span class="post_link_text">'.__('(previous entry)','avia_framework'))."</span>";?>
</div>   
    <div class='previous_post_link_align'>
<?php previous_post_link('<span class="next_post_link"><span class="post_link_text">'.__('(next entry)','avia_framework').'</span> %link &rarr;</span>'); ?>
</div>
```